# Make ground paths meet suspended paths

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

In RCT3 on the iPad, after struggling with creating paths over hilly terrain, I decided to put some of the paths in the air. This has worked for me in the past.

But now, I can't get the ground paths to meet up with the aerial paths so that guests can walk on them. Everything I have tried with every ground adjustment tool fails. If they would just give me finer control of the individual ground tile corners I could do it myself! But it seems that "adjust in increments" only adjusts *from the tile's current height*, meaning adjacent tiles can't even be brought to the same height manually. And the smoothing tool which I usually use to solve path joining simply fails with aerial paths because it only looks at the ground under the aerial path.

In this screen shot, you can see that I have two paths and a drink stand that won't join up. That sucks because an hour ago the left path and the drink stand worked fine!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have played RCT3 a lot and this bug also exists in the PC Version.
To prevent that this happens I always build ways like this:
I just started on a smooth ground and build up from there according to this screenshot:

[image: rct3]